# How to determine the total of solutions in complex

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find all the solutions in the complex set given the following equation
$(z-2)^5 = (3+2i)^2$
My question is whether it is solved using the formula of Euler for complex numbers or there is an alternative method to determine the solutions that the equation has in the field of complex numbers

Comment: By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, a polynomial $a_n z^n+a_{n-1} z^{n-1}+...+a_0$ of degree $n$ will have $n$ complex roots where $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It would be good to specify what methods you are limited to.  If you want to do it by hand, consider rewriting $3 + 2i = \sqrt{13} e^{i *\tan^{-1} (\frac{2}{3})}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(z-2)^5=13e^{2i\theta}$$
Where $\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$.
Can you take it from there? (I just used the polar form of a complex number).

Comment: Thanks, It has become very clear